# Segmentation fault in split function

Tags: multidimensional-array, split, segmentation-fault

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I am a new student (2 - 3 months) of 42 and currently working on my push_swap project. For this, I needed to implement my own split function. After working on it for 2 days, I still have a segmentation fault. Can you explain me my wrong doing? :-) Thank you so much in advance!

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

static size_t   count_words(char *str, char seperator)
{
    int     i;
    size_t  wordcount;

    i = 0;
    wordcount = 0;
    if (!str[i])
        return (0);
    while(str[i])
    {
        while (str[i] && str[i] == seperator)
            i++;
        if (str[i] && str[i] != seperator)
            wordcount += 1;
        while (str[i] && str[i] != seperator)
            i++;
    }
    return (wordcount);
}

static size_t   ft_wordlen (char *str, char seperator, int i)
{
    size_t wordlen;

    wordlen = 0;
    while (str[i] && str[i] != seperator)
    {   
        wordlen++;
        i++;
    }
    return (wordlen);
}

static int  malloc_free(char **split, int j, size_t buffersize)
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    split[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffersize);
    if (split[j] == NULL)
    {
        while (i < j)
            free (split[i++]);
        free(split);
        return (1);
    }
    return (0);
}

static char *ft_strlcpy(char *dest, char *src, int len)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    dest[len] = '\0';
    return (dest);
}

static int fill (char **split, char *str, char seperator)
{
    size_t  wordlen;
    int     i;
    int     j;
    
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {   
        while (str[i] && str[i] == seperator)
            i++;
        wordlen = ft_wordlen(str, seperator, i);
        if (wordlen > 0)
            if (malloc_free(split, j, wordlen + 1))
                return(1);
        ft_strlcpy(split[j], &str[i], wordlen);
        i = i + wordlen;
        j++;
    }
    return (0);
}

char **ft_split(char *str, char seperator)
{
    size_t  wordcount;

    wordcount = 0;
    wordcount = count_words(str, seperator);
    char **split = malloc(sizeof(char *) * (wordcount + 1));
    if (split == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    split[wordcount] = NULL;
    if (fill(split, str, seperator))
        return (NULL);
    return (split);
}
```

Tried this tester https://github.com/Ysoroko/FT_SPLIT_TESTER
It indicated me segmentation fault at Test4:|UNDEUXTROIS_| with '_' as sep. Why, oh why?